# How to check whether a file is present in a directory or not in PHP?

Tags: php, file, pdf, filenames, file-exists

Following is my code snippet:

```
<?php
$filename = $test_data['test_name'].".pdf";
//I want to check whether the above file with the same extension(.pdf) is existing in the directory having name say "ABC" is present or not
?>
```

And if such file is not present over there in the directory "ABC" then it should create the same.
And if the file is present in a directory "ABC" then it should get deleted.
I tried with the `file_exists()` but couldn't understood how to use it for a specific directory. 
Can anyone guide me in this regard please? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is this **ABC** directory ? Is it in the directory containing the PDF file or outside it ? Can you please include a directory tree in the question ?

Comment: in `file_exists()` you will probably have to pass the full path and not just the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and hope this would help.

```
$file_path  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/MyFolder/";
$file_name  = "abc.pdf";
if( file_exists( $file_path.$file_name ))  
{
    echo "File Exists";
}
else
{
    echo "File not found!!!";
}
```

Comment: It may be worth to mention that you should use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Because using "\" will fail in Linux and "/" will fail in Windows.

Comment: True but this can be a quick solution for the question asked. coder should try variations for sure

Answer (score 0):

file_exists use the absolute path to get file so use it like this :

```
     $directorypath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/to/your/directory/';
     $filename =  $directorypath  . $test_data['test_name'].".pdf";

     if (file_exists($filename)) {
         echo "The file $filename exists";
         //delete file 
         unlink('$filename');
    } else {
         echo "The file $filename does not exist"; 
    }
```

check this : http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: He asked if the file is in a directory named **ABC**

Answer (score 0):

use the combination of php functions unlink() ( to delete file ) and file_exists() ( to check if file exist).

```
Like


$filename = "./path to file/".$test_data['test_name'].".pdf";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
    if(unlink ($filename)){
    echo "deleted";
    }else{
    echo "not delete";
    }
} else {
    $file = fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($file,"your content");
    fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Function [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) is very useful.

```
file_flag=0;
    $input_file=scandir($full_path);
    foreach ($input_file as $input_name){
        if($input_name==$ABC)
                      file_flag=1;
                   else
                     file_flag=0;
                   }
            if (file_flag==1)
               echo "File exists!";
            else
               echo "File not found!";
```

Comment: Never scan to detect existance of a single file. file_exists() would be best practice. scandir() requires the largest effort, directory iterator ( FilesystemIterator ) or extraction ( glob() ) should be prefered.